# Number of groups of order $n$ being a semidirect product of non-trivial groups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product

It can be extremely difficult to determine the number of groups of order $n$ (upto isomorphism).

> Suppose a number $n$ is given and for every proper divisor $d|n$, we know the number of groups of order $d$. Is it then easy to calculate the number of groups of order $n$ (upto isomorphism) that can be expressed as a semidirect product of two or more non-trivial groups ?

According to my calcution with GAP, the groups upto order $59$ , cyclic groups not considered, that are NOT a semidirect product of smaller groups, are :

```
8  4    Q8
16  9    Q16
32  8    C2 . ((C4 x C2) : C2) = (C2 x C2) . (C4 x C2)
32  15    C4 . D8 = C4 . (C4 x C2)
32  20    Q32
32  32    (C2 x C2) . (C2 x C2 x C2)
48  28    C2 . S4 = SL(2,3) . C2
```

Comment: I don't see how just knowing the numbers of groups of orders dividing $n$ will help. To classify the semidirect prodcuts you need information about the automorphism groups of the individual groups.